# I was trying to run some code in my android studio but it keeps on showing compile error

Tags: flutter

I was trying to run flutter code but it keeps on showing following error.

I have tried updating the version of flutter_svg and cached_network_image but error still persists.

Compiler message:
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:335:20: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
          context: 'while resolving a picture',
                   ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:337:33: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
          informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                                ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:432:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:495:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:559:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:256:16: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
      context: context,
               ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:301:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'resolving a single-frame picture stream',
                 ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/svg.dart:158:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'picture failed to precache',
                 ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:399:35: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
            informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                                  ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:408:22: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
            context: 'in _Element.clipPath',
                     ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:798:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                              ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/svg/parser_state.dart:809:18: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
        context: 'in parseSvgElement',
                 ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/utilities/errors.dart:8:32: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DiagnosticsNode'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'DiagnosticsNode'.
      context: 'in $methodName',
                               ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.12.4+1/lib/src/utilities/errors.dart:10:29: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'Iterable Function()'.
      informationCollector: (StringBuffer buff) {
                            ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/zoomable_image-1.3.1/lib/src/zoomable_image.dart:174:30: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
    _imageStream.addListener(_handleImageLoaded);
                             ^
file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/zoomable_image-1.3.1/lib/src/zoomable_image.dart:186:33: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter%20Dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
Try changing the type of the parameter, or casting the argument to 'ImageStreamListener'.
    _imageStream.removeListener(_handleImageLoaded);
                                ^
Compiler failed on F:\Downloads\weo\lib\main.dart
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: What versions of dart, flutter_svg & cached_network_image are you using. For me it's working fine for cached_network_image: ^1.1.1,   flutter_svg: ^0.14.0 & dart 2.4.0

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I am using cached network image version 1.1.1 and flutter svg version 0.14.0 and I cannot share my whole code.